# TFS Build, how to specify multiple wildcard paths, when task uses a searchPattern (Find-Files)

Tags: tfsbuild

In TFS Build vNext, Build tasks can be used.  Many of which take a searchPattern parameter as input, for specifying wildcard paths of files.  For example, the VsTest task dictates the following for it's Test Assembly parameter:

> Test binaries to run tests on. Wildcards can be used. For example,
>   ***test*.dll;-:**\obj** for all dlls with test in name while excluding files in any sub-directory named obj.

So, a wildcard for paths to be included is specified, and a wildcard for paths to be excluded is specified.

How can I specify multiple wildcard paths to be *included*.

Say I want *foo*.dll but also *test*.dll, how can this be specified?

I've tried

```
**\*foo*.dll;**\*test*.dll
```

but the underlying powershell function Find-Files throws and error:

> The path is not of a legal form

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The followings works well on my machine

```
**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll;**\$(BuildConfiguration)\*foo*.dll;-:**\obj\**
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done. Depending on which build task you're using, you might need to prepend `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` (or some other placeholder) to inclusion expressions beyond the first.

I.e. the following should work:

```
**\*foo*.dll;$(build.sourcesDirectory)**\*test*.dll
```

See [this blog post](https://blogs.infosupport.com/tfs2015-build-tasks-the-wildcard-format-explained/) for the exact details of what is allowed in a wildcard expression.